# How do you add parameters to an email input field so only certain email addresses can be entered?

Tags: php, html

I have a very standard email input field going to an sql database

```
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" id="email"style = "display:inline; float:left;margin-left:5%;"/>
```

But I only want a certain type of email address to be entered,

e.g.

**myname@thisemailisallowed.com**

can be entered

but

**myname@notthisemailaddress.com**

cannot be entered

how can I do this?

Comment: I advise you to get into javascript if it's needed when the user is still typing, or else just do it in PHP on submit..

Comment: how do I do it in PHP on submit though?

Comment: @drew2 Build some validation, most likely with `preg_match`.